# I'm looking for a service/api that returns an image based on a keyword

Tags: images, web-services

For instance, if I want to show an image of a kitten, I could do something like this:

```
<img src="http://specialapi.com/kitten" />
```

If I want an image of a dog then I could to do something like this:

```
<img src="http://specialapi.com/dog" />
```

If I want it in Chinese I would to this:

```
<img src="http://specialapi.com/狗" />
```

Comment: And is it absolutely relevant that you do a `<img src=`, i.e. that you call it from a webpage?

Comment: I guess you want the images to be licensed with a license that allows you to show them on your website? Images without a license can not be reused.

Comment: Can you code? If so, use Python to invoke Google Image Search (or, as Nicolaus suggests, a Creative Commons licensed site) and scrape the results with [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org)

Comment: BTW, on technical grounds, I wuld not reommend `<img src="http://specialapi.com/kitten" />`, but, rather, `<img src="http://specialapi.com/search.php?subject=kitten" />`

Answer (score 1):

Can you code? Your participation on Stack Overview suggest that you can.

If so, use Python (or the language of your choice) to invoke the [Google Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) (or, as Nicolaus suggests, the [Creative Commons API](https://api.creativecommons.org/docs/)).

You can also scrape the results from other Creative Commons licensed sites with [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org)